# Erro ao importar imagem no react

Tags: html, css, react

Boa noite pessoal estou com esse erro no meu código e não sei como resolver, sou iniciante em react, vou mandando o print aqui do erro que fica aparecendo ao importar a imagem.[image: erro na iamgem]

a logo aparece na tela da minha aplicação porem toda vez que atualizo fica aparecendo a mensagem de erro. [image: erro na tela da aplicação]

fecho o erro e a imagem aparece como na imagem 3[image: logo aparece quando fecho o erro]

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um erro que acaba acontecendo no Typescript com React, ele tenta importar o conteúdo, mas tá vindo como um 'path' de caminho nas imagens, pra contornar esse erro tem duas soluções:

1º importar o caminho como string (Rápido)

```
const logo = require("../../assets/logo1.svg") as string;
```

2º Avisar ao Typescript para importar svg (Recomendado)

Crie um arquivo chamado custom.d.ts na raiz do projeto com o seguinte conteudo:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Adicione essa declaração no seu tsconfig.json

```
"include": ["src/components", "custom.d.ts"]
```

Acredito que uma dessas formas pode te ajudar, caso não tenta dar uma olhadinha nesse artigo: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Tenho uma coisa a comentar, como você comentou sobre a criação do arquivo custom.d.ts, na hora de adicionar ao tsconfig.json, ele não deveria ficar como "custom.d.ts" ao invés de adicionar também o "src/" ao path?

Comment: Verdade erro meu ali hehe, ele fica na raiz mesmo e tira esse src na hora de fazer o include